# What is a good alternative to the name variable for a language that only has immutable references or labels?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming, language-design, language-features

For example, in functional languages, **variables** are single assignment and their values are immutable once assigned. So they have two states **unbound** and **bound**, once bound they can't be changed.

Is there some mathematical term or other computer science term that is most appropriate for such as thing? Something that **semantically** doesn't imply variance or mutability.

If not there doesn't exist such as term and if you were designing a language that had such constructs, what other than the word **variable** would you use to for these?

I am **not** really looking to **poll** for ideas, I am trying to figure out if there is already an accepted industry ( any industry ) term for such a thing.

Comment: Just call them **immutables** ;)

Comment: final variable?

Comment: The mathematical term for these kinds of variables would be "variable". The concept of a mutable variable didn't really exist until programming languages entered the picture.

Comment: I disagree with @sepp2k. The term "variable" was introduced by Leibniz in his development of differential calculus, and it has been part of mathematics and physics since then. Those variable quantities necessarily need the possibility to change. Otherwise the idea of $\Delta x$ or $dx$ makes no sense.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold That's a different kind of change though. The question is about variables that can't be re-assigned and that's true of all variables in maths because there is no concept of re-assignment in mathematics.

Comment: @sepp2k I disagree. There _is_ a concept of re-assignment in mathematics, although it's traditionally not called that way. Mathematicians constantly introduce variables say x,y in their context (without assigning them a value) and assume something about them, say y+x=5. Next they may assume that x=1 and conclude y=4. They may drop the assumption x=1 and assume x=2 instead, and conclude  y=3. For me that's a change in x, and we are still talking about the same  variable x, since the assumption x+y=5 holds in both contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about "symbol"?

I saw a video on F# where the speaker said,

> you do not *assign* a value to a *variable*, you *bind* a value to a
>   *symbol*.

(Still looking for the reference for this.)

Whenever I encounter the word "variable" in places where such constructs are immutable, I silently think "bound symbol."

Answer (score 10):

Just call them variables. Math has variables; functional languages have the same kind of variables.

See also this essay by Bob Harper on this [terminology issue](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/words-matter/).

Comment: While this is along the lines of what I was looking for, the provided link, just stirs up more debate than answers.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, just take the linked essay as "why *variable* is an appropriate term"; feel free to ignore the part about "assignables".

Comment: yeah, the *assignables* is kind of a red-herring in that discussion. But personally I am still **semantically** stuck on the  **vary** part of *variables* and that fact that computer science isn't a 100% direct correlation to math terms in lots of cases.

Answer (score 4):

It's still a variable if it can take on various values in different invocations.  In other words, even though it can't be changed once assigned, that symbol can be assigned to different values initially.  That's in contrast to a *constant* which contains the same value every time it is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

constant, or const would probably be familiar to people using languages such as C and C++,

Answer (score 1):

*Name*. The same thing may be reasonably called by multiple names (`x = 4; y = 4`); and a name, once defined, never changes its referent. `x = 2; x = 3` makes just as little sense as saying that an octopus is not an octopus.

Comment: I like this, I was considering the term `label` but `name` works just and well if not better.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stick with that term? It may not be 100% appropriate, but when you choose a different name that will probably a cause of more misunderstandings than the ones you try to solve. Designers of other functional languages may had the same problem, but they decided to use the term "variable", either.

XSLT (which is widely used):

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_variable.asp

Haskell:

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-240003.2

Scheme:

http://www.scheme.com/tspl2d/binding.html

Erlang:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html

All of them are using the term "variable", too.

Of course, other language designers prefer to talk of "bindings" or "bound values", like here for F#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233238.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the contex "variable" or "binding" would work. I think "binding" is more likely to come up in statements like `let` in Haskell or Lisp.